# ASP.net inserted row in Datatable disappearing on page change

Tags: asp.net, insert, datatable, row, paging

So I have a datatable on my website and it displayed 10-20 rows of filled data. I have added a line of code that inserts a empty row in the existing datatable with the below code:

```
 dt.Rows.InsertAt(datatable.NewRow, 8)
```

I also have this which is required for doing paging in the datatable:

```
 Protected Sub GridView3_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView3.PageIndexChanging
    GridView3.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView3.DataBind()
End Sub
```

The problem is when I move from page 1 to 2 then back to 1, all the inserted rows disappear leaving only the filled rows. Is there a way to keep the inserted rows?? Or does anyone have any explanation or solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `DataBind` is rebuilding the `GridView` from its original data. You will need to make sure the data set you are binding to includes the added items. Typically, I have a method that gathers the items from the page and binds using those items.

In your case, you will just want to re-bind against the `DataTable` (named `dt` in your example code) when you add a new row.

```
GridView3.DataSource = dt
```

This means that you will have to keep it around somewhere. It is unclear from your code where the original `DataTable` comes from, so I don't really have any suggestions on where you might proceed next. And since your grid supports paging, my typical approach doesn't even work.

Simply put, because this is a web page, the server remembers nothing between postbacks that isn't persisted somewhere. Your options are to save it into the page somewhere, to save it to a database somewhere, or to save it to the session - a really bad idea for data sets of any significant size.

If you are going to be persisting the data eventually, you might be able to piggyback that persistence now - save it after the add and whenever edits are completed, the re-bind against the persisted data.

Comment: This sounds about right. Im calling databind several times though including page changes. Could you expand on this or provide an example, in the meantime ill try and make adjustments to my code. Then tick this as a correct.

Comment: Not really. I would need to know more about your data. I have tweaked my answer to say a bit more. You might find this site: http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip7.asp helpful, but probably not.